# Posted notifications showing date 'Thu, 1 Jan 1970' after a while

Tags: android, date, notifications, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am the developer of an application which is strong on the notifications department. I've recently upgraded to the HTC One X running Android 4.0.3 and noticed a problem that I never noticed on my previous phone running Android 2.1.

The notifications posted by my app do not set a date and a date has never been shown on my previous phone notifications. On my new phone, when the notifications are posted the date doesn't appear, but after a while, the 'Thu, 1 Jan 1970' date appears and I can't understand why.

When I say "after a while" I don't mean you keep staring at the screen for a few seconds/minutes and see the date appear. What I mean is after using the phone for a while, put it down, use it again, whatever, eventually, all the notifications posted by my app will have that date.

I've seen this happen a few times but I cannot find a pattern and understand when this happens to see if I can find a fix. Does anyone have any ideas why this might be happening on ICS?

I don't how relevant it can be but there's the whole code of my `postNotification` method:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext);

Intent intent = NoteEditorSingleActivity.createIntent(mContext);
intent.putExtra(AgendaNotesAdapter.KEY_ROW_ID, notifyId);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(mContext, (int)notifyId, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT));

builder.setContentTitle(noteTitle);
builder.setContentText(noteDescription);
builder.setSmallIcon(iconId);
builder.setTicker(noteTitle.length() > 0 ? noteTitle : null);
builder.setWhen(0);

Notification notification = builder.getNotification();

long noteSortOrder = Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD ? 1 : -1;

notification.flags = Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
notification.when = noteSortOrder * notifyId;

mNotificationManager.notify((int)notifyId, notification);
```

I know I'm setting the `when` to 0 with the builder and to a different value by changing the `when` value directly in the `notification` object. I can't remember why I did this initially but it's there for a reason.

What I don't understand is that the moment right after calling the `notify()` method and look at the notification in the status bar, there is no date. Why does it appear after some time of using the phone.

That's what I want to know and fix.

Comment: It's worth commenting midnight AM, 1 Jan 1970, UTC (GMT) is the date associated with time = 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your notification's `when` should be set to the time you  want it display (in milliseconds since the UNIX epoch: January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC).  Setting it to 0 is a popular but undocumented (and therefore not guaranteed to work) way to not show any timestamp.

You don't show where `notifyId` is set, but you're presumably setting `when` to a low number of milliseconds since the epoch here:

```
notification.when = noteSortOrder * notifyId;
```

The reason you're setting it to `0` first and then changing it later is that you're using another undocumented hack, trying to affect how the system places your notification in relation to others. By building the notification (with `builder.getNotification()`) with `when` set to 0, you're getting its View laid out without a timestamp.  Then you're changing the timestamp to affect the sort order before calling `notify()`.

The fact that ICS happens to actually end up showing your notification with the very low timestamp you set is something that may or may not be fixable. It might just be that ICS ends up re-laying-out your notification after some time, which of course would use the last timestamp you gave it.

Personally, I think the best option is to remove the hacks.  (Well, I think you could *probably* get away with setting the timestamp to `0` to hide the timestamp altogether, but the sort order hack seems like asking for trouble.)

Comment: Yeah, maybe... I think I added the sort order hack because they changed the order the notifications appear from Gingerbread to ICS (probably to Honeycomb but I really didn't test my app much on Honeycomb, so can't tell). I'll have to rethink a bunch of things about the notifications in my app and see what's the best solution to avoid unpredictable behavior like this.

Comment: I just though of a possible solution... I could use a `RemoteView` and use my own layout while also keeping the sort order hack. The only problem is that I really wanted my notifications to have the same style as the OS (AOSP, Sense, Touchwiz, etc...). Is there a way to pull the notifications layout at runtime? That would be the solution as I could easily hide the timestamp view.